# Who to credit for "control functions" in econometrics?

Tags: econometrics, references, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

The idea is pretty simple, and I think it came out sort of by-the-way in a paper about something else, so I'm having a hard time figuring out who to cite.

Basically you've got a GLM (like a probit or something)
$$
g(y) = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon
$$

$X$ is endogenous, $Z$ is an instrument.  Turns out that it works to get

$$
X = \hat{f}(Z)
$$
then calculate

$$
\zeta = X-\hat{X}
$$

then fit
$$
g(y) = \alpha+\beta X + f(\hat\zeta)+\epsilon
$$

([One can do this in the GAM context](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsmj.sagepub.com%2Fcontent%2F11%2F6%2F581.abstract&ei=ZOvoVILoBsLwoAT89IHIDg&usg=AFQjCNFfXyZKCvvN-OKjwsRpWowp4qbN8w&sig2=scFGOzPyb8BUKeuGLPYd6A&bvm=bv.86475890,d.cGU), which is actually why I am interested).

The econometrics literature from the 1970s is a little opaque (to me anyway), and this sort of estimator was explored in the context of correlated random coefficients models (I think).  I've come across some consideration of similar estimators in a Heckman paper:

J. J. Heckman, “Dummy endogenous variables in a simultaneous equation system,” Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society, pp. 931–959, 1978.

but Marra & Radice cite a "Hausman-like approach" in their paper on 2-stage generalized additive models.  Which Hausman paper would this be?  It isn't clear in the 2SGAM paper.

Comment: Hi, If you're talking about instrumental variables, then this link gives some background on the history of it. But, my apologies if you're not talking about that.http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/ftrebbi/research/ST_JEP_2003.pdf

Comment: I am indeed talking about IV, but a specific may of doing it in the context of nonlinear models.  It might be one of those things that is so basic that it isn't typically cited.

Comment: Oh Okay. Thanks for the explanation. I'm only familiar with it in the context of linear models. Sometimes you can email one of the econometrics wizards and they respond kindly. Sometimes not also !!! All the best.

Comment: it also works in linear models, but it is less convenient than $(z'x)^{-1}z'y$